# Autofac: Resolving an IEnumerable of registrations on the same name

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I am using Autofac to handle dependency injection in my application. In order not to have to do every single registration explicitly, I first use `RegisterAssemblyTypes().AsImplementedInterfaces()` and then only take care of those that need to be specially configured.

I have an interface called `IToolStripPopulator` that has a few different implementations, several of which are in use, but some aren't anymore (as I'm trying to work SOLIDly and adhere to OCP, I am usually not changing them if I need different functionality, but rather leave them alone and create new ones that do what I need now). For that reason I need to overwrite the automatic registration for the interface, in two ways:

- One implementation is to be injected into my main logic and acts as a decorator for a few of the others. I naturally want this to be registered via `As<IToolStripPopulator>()` and be done with it as this is the implementation my application's functionality currently depends on.
- Those other implementations are the "inner" populators only to be used within that decorator class. To inject them, there are two ways:

  - Explicitly wiring up the constructor for the outer implementation with the specific types; this is not very nice, also because that constructor would have to take the exact number of inner populators I am using *right now*, which is not OCP compliant.
  - Have the outer implementation take an `IEnumerable<IToolStripPopulator>`; this is what I'd like to do, but it's also where I'm stuck.

I can't let Autofac resolve that `IEnumerable` on its own, because it would just resolve all implementations of the interface, even those that I'm not using anymore as well as the "outer" that I don't want in there (and which would probably cause an endless loop during resolution).

So what I'd like to do is this:

```
// the inner populators
builder.RegisterType<BrowsersMenuPopulator>().Named<IToolStripPopulator>("inner");
builder.RegisterType<ThreadsafeConnectionMenuPopulator>().Named<IToolStripPopulator>("inner");

// the decorator implementation
builder.RegisterType<BrowserAndConnectionMenuPopulator>().As<IToolStripPopulator>().WithParameter( ? );
```

But there is no way to actually access the existing registrations at that point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

....and here I tried just one more thing which I didn't actually expect to work, but it did.

```
builder.Register(c => c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IToolStripPopulator>>("inner")).As<IEnumerable<IToolStripPopulator>>();
```

does not, as I would have expected, try to resolve an `IEnumerable<IToolStripPopulator>` registration named "inner", but an `IEnumerable` of `IToolStripPopulator` registrations named "inner" - exactly as I need it.

This will then correctly be resolved and injected into the decorator implementation just from having that registered `As<IToolStripPopulator>()` with no further configuration.

From a formal aspect I would actually have preferred being able to state the name by which to resolve directly with the decorator registration because that would be more intuitive and flexible (what if I need to resolve several `IEnumerable<IToolStripPopulator>`?), but in many cases this should be enough.

@codinghorror's concept of "rubber duck problem solving" rules my every workday....

Comment: Hey, I just needed that. Thanks me!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to directly specify that I know of is to "new-up" directly in your registration code:

```
//decorator impl
builder.Register(c => new BrowserAndConnectionMenuPopulator(c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IToolStripPopulator>>("inner"),...)).As<IToolStripPopulator>();
```

This has the advantage of specifying directly in the registration the exact required dependencies, but the disadvatage of loss of flexibility in reconfiguring `BrowserAndConnectionMenuPopulator`'s dependencies.  I included this for completeness, but honestly I prefer the solution you discovered.